# How do I return the decimal portion of a number?

Tags: excel, vba, modulo

I have a data table that has values in column A consisting of integers and decimal numbers. (e.g. 1; 2; 3; 3.1; 3.2; 4... etc.).

I am trying to loop thru column A, find any values that are not integers and delete that entire row.

I am attempting to use the Mod function. I take the value of the cell in column A and when dividing that by 1, if the remainder is not zero delete the row.

My remainder is always zero, even when doing 10.1 Mod 1 for example.

```vb
Dim c As Range
Dim remainder As Variant
Dim rowNum As Integer

For Each c In Worksheets("BOM Dump").Range("A1:A1000").Cells
    
    'Range("L1").Value = "Number"
    'Range("M1").Value = c
   
    remainder = c.Value Mod 1
    Range("N2").Value = remainder
    
    If remainder <> 0 Then
        rowNum = c.Row
        Rows(rowNum).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Comment: `# Mod 1` will always return 0. Mod function treats everything as integers. multiply your stuff first to get it into integer range.

Comment: `remainder = c.Value - Fix(c.Value)`

Comment: Second issue you're going to run into is you need to iterate backwards, not forwards otherwise you'll delete the wrong stuff

Comment: Or rather miss stuff...

Comment: ^^^^ Iterate backwards, or use `Union` to build up a range to delete and only delete *after* looping.

Comment: If you're dealing with large data sets, it might be faster to pull everything into an array, remove what's not needed, then just replace the whole dataset with your output array.

Comment: @bigben `Fix` seems to be `rounddown()`? that's way faster than app.wrkshtfunc...rounddown... Thanks!

Comment: @BigBen Wait... no I use `Cint` what's the difference between Cint and Fix?>

Comment: @bigben. NVM i looked it up myself. thank god for internet,

Comment: Thanks both of you, @bigben using the Fix() works better for me than multiplying for Mod because its not always just one decimal place. Now....to figure out how to iterate backwards.

Comment: `For i = 1000 to 1 Step -1`. `Set c = Worksheets("BOM Dump").Range("A" & i)`.

Answer (score 1):

Used `fix` instead of `Mod` and iterated backwards to get it working perfectly. Thanks everyone.

```
For i = 500 To 1 Step -1
        Set c = Worksheets("BOM Dump").Range("A" & i)
       
        remainder = c.Value - Fix(c.Value)
        
        If remainder <> 0 Then
            rowNum = c.Row
            Rows(rowNum).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
```